# Getting toGeoJSON is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet, turfjs

i'm trying to find the number of point in a polygon using [turf.js](https://turfjs.org) but when i run the code below, i'm getting "*Uncaught TypeError: turf.featureCollection(...).toGeoJSON is not a function*".

```
var healthCollection = turf.featureCollection(health)
var adminCollection = turf.featureCollection(admin)
console.log(healthCollection);
console.log(admin);

var points = turf.pointsWithinPolygon(healthCollection.toGeoJSON() , adminCollection.toGeoJSON());
console.log(points);
```

Comment: Please include a [mre]

Comment: Where are you getting `toGeoJSON` from? It doesn't appear in the documentation.

Comment: @Andy. i am getting toGeoJSON from leaflet